# How do I use regex in PHP to find a number surrounded by spaces?

Tags: php, regex

With regex/PHP I'm trying to extract a number from a sting, but only if the number has a blank space before it and another after it.

Right now I have this:

```
$tacNO = number_format(intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/','',$row[tactical])));
```

It works to get the number, but I need to adjust the regedit to test for the  included spaces, and return only the number. Can that be done using lookbehind and lookahead? What would accomplish that?

Comment: just use a group to capture the numbers \s(\d+)\s

Comment: What if the number is at start or end of the string ? do you still wanna match, i.e `123 ` or `some blah blah  123` ?

Comment: Only if its the first part of the sting followed by a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex like `\s[0-9]+\s` would capture any number with a white-space on either side.
If you want to make sure the characters on either side are spaces (not tabs etc.) then use this instead: `[ ][0-9]+[ ]`
If you want to match numbers that only have white-space on one side use the * quantifier after the white-space identifiers.

Like [lagripe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8004593/lagripe) said, a capturing group would probably be the best way to do this.
You can use a capturing group by surrounding the desired part with parentheses: `[ ]([0-9]+)[ ]`.
Alternatively, you can add a non-capturing group to the spaces: `(?:[ ])[0-9]+(?:[ ])`. What this does is uses them to match the string, but ignores them when giving the output.

If you want to test out your regex strings, the website [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is my personal favorite.

Comment: I'm very new at regex and don't know from "capturing groups". I would need a good example.

Comment: Tried this but no joy.  $tacNO = number_format(intval(preg_replace('\s[0-9]+\s','',$row[tactical])));

Comment: After some more research, I think your best option is to use no capturing groups on the spaces. I have added an example to the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You could use lookarounds as follows:

```
$num = preg_match("/(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s)/", $row[tactical], $matches);
$tacNO = number_format(intval($matches[0]));
```

Or, you could use explicit spaces in the pattern and instead use a capture group to isolate the number match:

```
$num = preg_match("/\s+(\d+)\s+/", $row[tactical], $matches);
$tacNO = number_format(intval($matches[1]));
```